# Which is faster: ( arr.contains(val) || $.inArray(val,arr) )?

Tags: ember.js

Which is faster?

```
arr.contains(val);
```

or

```
$.inArray(val, arr);
```

is there an accurate way to test?

Comment: @Adriano - its an ember function [Ember contains() doc](http://docs.emberjs.com/symbols/Ember.Enumerable.html#method=.contains)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for an easy way to benchmark JS, I'd suggest jsperf.com.